# Add values from different columns and order then

Tags: awk

I am trying to achieve the following, but I am completely new in the topic of programming, and I am getting crazy. I have seen many examples where it is explained how to make the sum of a column or so, but never how to add values from the same row. I have tried to do something with the `awk` command, but it was completely useless...

I have this input:

```
10000   4.32078125e-05 2.319742728e-05 -1.626118465e-06 2.116442767e-05 2.824876608e-06 -2.008498137e-07 1.378852315e-11 -2.461344776e-11 -1.185369303e-11 -4.711965783e-11 -7.488327241e-10 -1.133857758e-08
```

In order not to get crazy with so many numbers, it is something like:

```
#Iteration #FpX #FpY #FpZ #FvX #FvY #FvZ #MpX #MpY #MpZ #MvX #MvY #MvZ
```

And I need the following output (first line is text):

```
Iteration      FX        FY         FZ         MX       MY        MZ
#Iteration #FpX+#FvX #FpY+#FvY  #FpZ+#FvZ  #MpX+#MvX #MpY+#MvY #MpZ+#MvZ
```

Comment: +1 for providing input and expected output, next time don't be afraid to also show your efforts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can reference the `<N>`th column (field) via `$<N>`, e.g. `$1` which you can use to do your arithmetics:

```
$ cat foo.input
10000   4.32078125e-05 2.319742728e-05 -1.626118465e-06 2.116442767e-05 2.824876608e-06 -2.008498137e-07 1.378852315e-11 -2.461344776e-11 -1.185369303e-11 -4.711965783e-11 -7.488327241e-10 -1.133857758e-08
10001   1              2               3                4               5               6                7               8                9                10               11               12

$ awk \
    'BEGIN { printf "%-11s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s\n", "Iteration", "FX", "FY", "FZ", "MX", "MY", "MZ"  }
     NF    { printf "%-11s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s %-12s\n", $1, $2+$5, $3+$6, $4+$7, $8+$11, $9+$12, $10+$13 }' foo.input
Iteration   FX           FY           FZ           MX           MY           MZ
10000       6.43722e-05  2.60223e-05  -1.82697e-06 -3.33311e-11 -7.73446e-10 -1.13504e-08
10001       5            7            9            17           19           21
```

Answer (score 0):

If you donot need the header this works:

```
perl -lane 'push @a,$F[0];
            for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){
            $i+=3 if($i==4);
            push @a,$F[$i]+$F[$i+3]}
            print "@a"' your_file
```

Tested below:

```
> perl -lane 'push @a,$F[0];for($i=1;$i<13;$i++){$i+=3 if($i==4);push @a,$F[$i]+$F[$i+3]}print "@a"' temp
10000 6.437224017e-05 2.6022303888e-05 -1.8269682787e-06 -3.333113468e-11 -7.7344617186e-10 -1.135043127303e-08 -4.711965783e-11 -7.488327241e-10 -1.133857758e-08
```